# How to export a map into a low resolution image in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer

The only way I know how to export a map view into an image is to resize the window and from there export it. But I want a separate ocean layer included in the image, so I click Zoom Full before making the ocean layer visible. I tried increasing the width of the panels to hide some areas I don't want included in the export, but the software stubbornly automatically adjusts the map zoom level, map extent, and the panel widths.

So I tried using Print Composer, which I try to avoid because of its complexity.

The only thing I can find is Add Map, but it must be dragged so that it is loaded into the canvas. Upon loading the map, the map extent and zoom level was very different from the QGIS main window.

Why can't I just paste it directly into the canvas so that the map extent is not modified?

I have several maps I plan to have the same resolution, but I could not find any plugins that would make exporting easier.

How can I export into a fixed map view into a low resolution image?

Answer (score 5):

Print composer is really very good, and one of the strengths of QGIS. It is worth spending some time to learn how to use it.

You can change the extent of the map in the print canvas to match QGIS by clicking the `Set to map canvas extent` button in the right hand panel in the `Item properties` tab

[image]

Note:

When resizing your map in the QGIS main window you may have to slightly move the map for the `Set to map canvas extent` to work.

If your print composer is in portrait, it doesn't correspond with the QGIS window as well so you will need to play around with the zoom levels and keep clicking `Set to map canvas extent` until you get it how you want it.

Then you can use `Export as image`

[image]